# Change ImageView image in another fragment. Android

Tags: android, string, replace, imageview, fragment

There are two pieces. One button. On the other ImageView. How to make so that by pressing the buttons on the first fragment loaded a certain image in the ImageView, which in the second fragment.

Fragment 2:

```
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_barcode_page1, container, false);
        logoIMG = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.logoIMG);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        return view;
    }
```

But at the touch of a button change image application closes

Comment: could you please share some more code? e.g. the code that's executed after the button click would be very helpful

Comment: If you want to change in the other fragment use `getActivity().findViewById();`instead of `getView().findViewById();`

Comment: That handler on the button
[code] BarCodePage1Fragment barCodePage1Fragment = (BarCodePage1Fragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.logoIMG);
                    barCodePage1Fragment.logoIMG.setImageResource(R.drawable.triskovorodki_big); [/code]

Comment: Check official docs  https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static variable for that.

Example:- **ImageFragment**

```
//global public and static ImageView
public static ImageView imageView;
.....

//Initialize the imageview somewhere
public setupView(){
    imageView = getView().findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
}
```

**ButtonFragment**

Inside onClick of the button do something like this.

```
ImageFragment.imageView.setImageDrawable(//your drawable//);
```

**Note**: The imageView in the ImageFragment mus be initialized, means the fragment should be always initialized before using in other class.

Comment: Does not work.
Handler on the button
ImageFragment.imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logo_big));